# Why can pygame.event.get() only be called once per frame

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, methods, pygame

I was writing a function to make it easy to detect a key press without having to use the for loop that is normally used:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == key:
```

And I found that the function that I had written didn't work, and this is because I have this `test_for_quit` function in all my projects that runs every frame. I've found this to be useful as I can just copy this into any program that I'm writing:

```
def test_for_quit():
    '''Shuts down the game if it's closed'''
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
```

Surprisingly this is the first game I've made since implementing that function to all my programs, that doesn't use key presses. But I found that the reason that the new function that I've written didn't work because `pygame.event.get()` had already been called in the `test_for_quit` function.

After some more testing I found that this method cannot be called twice, for instance:

```
while True:
    print(pygame.event.get())
    print() #Leaves an empty line
    print(pygame.event.get())
```

returns:

```
[<Event(17-VideoExpose {})>, <Event(16-VideoResize {'h': 600, 'size': (800, 600), 'w': 800})>, <Event(1-ActiveEvent {'gain': 0, 'state': 1})>, <Event(4-MouseMotion {'rel': (538, 315), 'pos': (537, 314), 'buttons': (0, 0, 0)})>]

[]
```

So why is it that pygame.event.get() can only be called once, this really intrigues me and I couldn't find anything about it on the internet?

Also I've decided to not continue using the `test_for_quit` function and the `key_down` function in favour of just using the traditional for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`event.get` can be called as many times as you want.  The matter is it does take the events out of the event queue - and is up to your program to consume them.  When it is called a second time with no interval (pygame itself knows nothing about "frames" - you give the delay between frames) - all events are gone, and no others have been generated.

The documentation for `event.get` reads:

This will get all the messages and remove them from the queue. If a type or sequence of types is given only those messages will be removed from the queue.

```
If you are only taking specific events from the queue, be aware that the queue could eventually fill up with the events you are not interested.
```

You have two choices: keep your "copy and pasted" call to event.get and read the keyboard state by using other calls -  `pygame.key.get_pressed` for one - or to use a smarter way to consume the events in the queue.

There are even ways to check for events on the event queue without consuming them - so you could place those calls before a call to `events.get`.

One is that the function itself allows you to specify event types you are interested in. So let's suppose you have a function to deal with mouse events and a function to deal with keyboard events:

```
def do_keys():
    for event in pygame.event.get(KEYDOWN):
         ...

def do_mouse():
    for event in pygame.event.get((MOUSEMOTION, MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)):
        ..
def main():
    while True:
        do_keys()
        do_mouse()
        # discard other events:
        pygame.event.get()
        # draw screen
        ...
        pygame.time.delay(...)
```

Or, which is even easier, you can simply assign the return value of the call to `pygame.event.get` to a variable - that will be a single list over which you can iterate as many times as you wish.

```
events = pygame.event.get()
for event in events:
    # treat some events here
# some other logic here
...
do_keyboard_things(events)

def do_keyboard_things(events):
    for event in events:
         ...
```